# object has no attribute error with python3

Tags: python-3.x

I have a error when trying to call calculate_similarity2 function which in in DocSim.py file from my notebook.

The error message is : `'DocSim' object has no attribute 'calculate_similarity2'`

Here the content of my docsim File :

```
import numpy as np

class DocSim(object):
    def __init__(self, w2v_model , stopwords=[]):
        self.w2v_model = w2v_model
        self.stopwords = stopwords





    def vectorize(self, doc):
        """Identify the vector values for each word in the given document"""
        doc = doc.lower()
        words = [w for w in doc.split(" ") if w not in self.stopwords]
        word_vecs = []
        for word in words:
            try:
                vec = self.w2v_model[word]
                word_vecs.append(vec)
            except KeyError:
                # Ignore, if the word doesn't exist in the vocabulary
                pass

        # Assuming that document vector is the mean of all the word vectors
        # PS: There are other & better ways to do it.
        vector = np.mean(word_vecs, axis=0)

        return vector


    def _cosine_sim(self, vecA, vecB):
        """Find the cosine similarity distance between two vectors."""
        csim = np.dot(vecA, vecB) / (np.linalg.norm(vecA) * np.linalg.norm(vecB))
        if np.isnan(np.sum(csim)):
            return 0
        return csim

    def calculate_similarity(self, source_doc, target_docs=[], threshold=0):
        """Calculates & returns similarity scores between given source document & all
        the target documents."""
        if isinstance(target_docs, str):
            target_docs = [target_docs]

        source_vec = self.vectorize(source_doc)
        results = []
        for doc in target_docs:
            target_vec = self.vectorize(doc)
            sim_score = self._cosine_sim(source_vec, target_vec)
            if sim_score > threshold:
                results.append({
                    'score' : sim_score,
                    'sentence' : doc
                })
            # Sort results by score in desc order
            results.sort(key=lambda k : k['score'] , reverse=True)

        return results

    def calculate_similarity2(self, source_doc=[], target_docs=[], threshold=0):
    """Calculates & returns similarity scores between given source document & all the target documents."""
        if isinstance(source_doc, str):
            target_docs = [source_doc]
            if isinstance(target_docs, str):
                target_docs = [target_docs]
                #source_vec = self.vectorize(source_doc)
                results = []
                for doc in source_doc:
                    source_vec = self.vectorize(doc)
                    for doc1 in target_docs:
                        target_vec = self.vectorize(doc)
                        sim_score = self._cosine_sim(source_vec, target_vec)
                        if sim_score > threshold:
                            results.append({
                                'score' : sim_score,
                                'source sentence' : doc,
                                'target sentence' : doc1
                            })
                        # Sort results by score in desc order
                        results.sort(key=lambda k : k['score'] , reverse=True)
        return results
```

here in instruction code when i try to call the fucntion :

To create DocSim Object

```
ds = DocSim(word2vec_model,stopwords=stopwords)

sim_scores = ds.calculate_similarity2(source_doc, target_docs)
```

the error message is :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-54-bb0bd1e0e0ad> in <module>()
----> 1 sim_scores = ds.calculate_similarity2(source_doc, target_docs)

AttributeError: 'DocSim' object has no attribute 'calculate_similarity2'
```

i don't undersantand how to resolve this problem.

I can access to all function except calculate_similarity2

Can you help me please?

thanks

Comment: You define `calculate_similarity2` as an inner function in the initializer, so it indeed doesn't become a method of your class. Move the function definition outside the initializer and you'll be fine.

Comment: As a side note: you don't want to use a mutable container as a default value for a function argument (the `stopwords` argument to your initializer), cf https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/#mutable-default-arguments

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers thanks for your response, same problem always, i've just edit my post

Comment: Using a __proper__ MCVE (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) I don't get this issue so the code you posted is obviously not the one you get the error with. Note that you can get unexpected results if mixing tabs and spaces so make sure you ONLY use spaces for indentation (the tabnanny module can detect this kind of issues).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have defined the `calculate_similarity2` function inside the `__init__` scope. Try getting it out of there

Comment: Thanks RanAB, The same problem presist even when I get the fucntion out

Comment: Can u show us the code you are trying to run? Have you made an instance of class DocSim?

Comment: i just edit my post, can you check it please? Thanks

Comment: Well, since the exception has nothing to do with the code itself, I would say you might have some tabs and spaces mixed up there. Try running the code with python -tt to verify.

Comment: Sorry i don't uderstand, the exception has a relation with my error?

Comment: I meant that the exception has nothing to do with what the function is supposed to preform, . it means that the content of the functions in your code are irrelevant to the issue, which leads to the conclusion that it might be tabs and spaces problem.  Try opening a console if you are using windows or shell if you are using linux and run `python -tt DocSim.py'

Comment: Ok when I try  with `python -tt DocSim.py', no error messsage

Comment: But,  when I recall this from my notebook 'sim_scores = ds.calculate_similarity2(source_doc, target_docs)' i got the same eroor

Comment: What is the meaning from your notebook? Running python -tt DocSim.py should not only notify you of any errors, but it runs the code as well. Did you not get the exception again ?

Comment: Have you restarted / reloaded your "notebook" ? A running python shell will not automagically detect and reload update source code (or at least not reliably).